# Janusgraph unable to connect to Hbase

Tags: java, hbase, gremlin, janusgraph

I downloaded Janusgraph, unzipped it, and am trying to connect to it through gremlin. I want to use HBase as a storage backend.

I ran the following commands:

```
JanusGraph g = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "hbase").set("storage.hostname", [SERVERNAME]).set("storage.port", "2181").set("storage.hbase.ext.zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-secure").set("storage.hbase.table", "test").open();
```

And also tried:

```
JanusGraph g = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend","hbase").set("storage.hostname,[SERVERNAME]).set("storage.hbase.ext.zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbasesecure").set("storage.hbase.table", "test").set("cache.db-cache-time","180000").set("cache.db-cache-size","0.5").set("cache.db-cache-cleanwait","20").set("cache.db-cache", "true").open();
```

And got the following exception.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

> org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager  - Unexpected exception during getDeployment()
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
>   at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getDeployment(HBaseStoreManager.java:370)
>   at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getFeatures(HBaseStoreManager.java:409)
>   at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1383)
>   at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:164)
>   at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:133)
>   at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:80)
>   at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory$open.call(Unknown Source)
>   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure out the same issue. I think the problem is that Janusgraph 0.4.0 is not compatible with HBase 1.x (despite what the release notes say) and am trying an older version of Janusgraph to test out that theory.

Source: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1723

Comment: Have you been able to get it to run on Hbase 2.x?  I tried every version of Janus I could get my hands on, but could not get it to work with Hbase 1.x.  Unfortunately, that is a requirement for me.  I'll have to trace through it and see if I can get a pull request with a fix out whenever I get time to look at it

Comment: I tried Janusgraph 0.3.2 with HBase 1.4.9. That seems to start up, but I get a different error when trying to commit anything to the graph (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57874448/janusgraph-0-3-2-hbase-1-4-9-cant-set-graph-timestamps).
That's as far as I've gotten so far. I'll update if I figure anything out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Janus Graph 0.6.1 working with HBase 1.x server using the following approach. Checkout Janus Graph source code from Github, build the source code on your local machine using the following maven command

```
mvn clean install -pl janusgraph-hbase -am -DskipTests -Denforcer.skip=true -Drat.skip=true -Dgpg.skip=true -Dhbase.profile -Pjanusgraph-release,hbase1
```

Then use the produced maven artefact as dependency in your project.