# Janusgraph 0.3.2 + HBase 1.4.9 - Can't set graph.timestamps

Tags: java, hbase, gremlin, janusgraph

I am running Janusgraph 0.3.2 in a docker container and trying to use an AWS EMR cluster running HBase 1.4.9 as the storage backend. I can run gremlin-server.sh, but if I try to save something, I get the stack trace pasted below. It looks to me like the locks are being created using different timestamps lengths causing it to look like no lock exists.

I tried adding the graph.timestamps setting to the config file, but still got the same error.

Here is my configuration
gremlin-server.yml

```
host: 0.0.0.0
port: 8182
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WsAndHttpChannelizer
graphs: {
  graph: conf/gremlin-server/janusgraph-hbase-server.properties
}
... more ...
```

janusgraph-hbase-server.properties

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=hbase
storage.hostname=${HBASE_HOSTNAME}
storage.port=2181

cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5

graph.timestamps=MILLI
```

Notes: I thought that graph.timestamps=MILLI would fix the problem due to the mismatched timestamps shown in the stack trace. Zookeeper is running only on HBase master, so HBASE_HOSTNAME gets filled in the the fqdn of HBase master.

```
15:52:33 WARN  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker  - Skipping outdated lock on KeyColumn [k=0x 80-241-255- 61- 16-165-160-118-108- 30- 97-112-112-108-105- 99- 97-116-105-111-238, c=0x  0] with our rid ( 48- 97- 50- 97- 48- 50- 51- 55- 50- 53- 57- 45-106- 97-110-117-115-103-114- 97-112-104- 45- 48- 49) but mismatched timestamp (actual ts 2019-09-10T15:52:33.016Z, expected ts 2019-09-10T15:52:33.016089Z)
15:52:33 ERROR org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph  - Could not commit transaction [1] due to storage exception in system-commit
org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException: Could not execute operation due to backend exception
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:56)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.persist(CacheTransaction.java:91)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.flushInternal(CacheTransaction.java:139)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.commit(CacheTransaction.java:196)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.commit(BackendTransaction.java:151)
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.commit(StandardJanusGraph.java:713)
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.commit(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1382)
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem.commit(ManagementSystem.java:246)
        at org.janusgraph.core.schema.JanusGraphManagement$commit$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:236)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:71)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:196)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.super$3$execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:72)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:122)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:95)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:165)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:165)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:89)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:236)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:146)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:236)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:453)
Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.PermanentLockingException: Permanent locking failure
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.AbstractLocker.checkLocks(AbstractLocker.java:359)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingTransaction.checkAllLocks(ExpectedValueCheckingTransaction.java:175)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingTransaction.prepareForMutations(ExpectedValueCheckingTransaction.java:154)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.mutateMany(ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.java:72)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:94)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:91)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:68)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:54)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.PermanentBackendException: Read 1 locks with our rid  48- 97- 50- 97- 48- 50- 51- 55- 50- 53- 57- 45-106- 97-110-117-115-103-114- 97-112-104- 45- 48- 49 but mismatched timestamps; no lock column contained our timestamp (2019-09-10T15:52:33.016089Z)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker.checkSeniority(ConsistentKeyLocker.java:528)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker.checkSingleLock(ConsistentKeyLocker.java:454)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker.checkSingleLock(ConsistentKeyLocker.java:118)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.AbstractLocker.checkLocks(AbstractLocker.java:351)
        ... 60 more
15:52:33 ERROR org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph  - Could not commit transaction [1] due to exception
org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException: Could not execute operation due to backend exception
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:56)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.persist(CacheTransaction.java:91)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.flushInternal(CacheTransaction.java:139)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction.commit(CacheTransaction.java:196)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.commit(BackendTransaction.java:151)
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.commit(StandardJanusGraph.java:713)
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.commit(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1382)
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem.commit(ManagementSystem.java:246)
        at org.janusgraph.core.schema.JanusGraphManagement$commit$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:236)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:71)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:196)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.super$3$execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:72)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:122)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:95)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:165)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:165)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:89)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:236)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:146)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:236)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:453)
Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.PermanentLockingException: Permanent locking failure
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.AbstractLocker.checkLocks(AbstractLocker.java:359)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingTransaction.checkAllLocks(ExpectedValueCheckingTransaction.java:175)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingTransaction.prepareForMutations(ExpectedValueCheckingTransaction.java:154)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.mutateMany(ExpectedValueCheckingStoreManager.java:72)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:94)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.cache.CacheTransaction$1.call(CacheTransaction.java:91)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:68)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:54)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.PermanentBackendException: Read 1 locks with our rid  48- 97- 50- 97- 48- 50- 51- 55- 50- 53- 57- 45-106- 97-110-117-115-103-114- 97-112-104- 45- 48- 49 but mismatched timestamps; no lock column contained our timestamp (2019-09-10T15:52:33.016089Z)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker.checkSeniority(ConsistentKeyLocker.java:528)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker.checkSingleLock(ConsistentKeyLocker.java:454)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.consistentkey.ConsistentKeyLocker.checkSingleLock(ConsistentKeyLocker.java:118)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.AbstractLocker.checkLocks(AbstractLocker.java:351)
        ... 60 more
Could not commit transaction due to exception during persistence
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Janusgraph JanusGraphException Could not commit transaction due to exception during persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58916854/janusgraph-janusgraphexception-could-not-commit-transaction-due-to-exception-dur)

Answer (score 0):

I come across this issue as I'm facing similar one.
As said in this post: [Janusgraph JanusGraphException Could not commit transaction due to exception during persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58916854/janusgraph-janusgraphexception-could-not-commit-transaction-due-to-exception-dur)
we should set the graph.timestamps property value to NANO.
Not really understand how this works.

Comment: Thanks for the link! If you believe that a question is wholly or mostly answered in the answer to another question, please use the Flag link to flag it as a duplicate, instead of posting an answer with a simple link.